# mysql find matching key with mismatched value

Tags: mysql

I am working with a database that has some duplicate data and am trying to write a query that will pull the problem data.  The table looks like:

```
lpID, pID, pName, etc...
```

where lpID is the unique id for this table and pID is a shared id for the whole db.  I have this to pull matching pID values (16k):

```
SELECT lp.pID, group_concat(lp.lpID) as lpIDs, group_concat(lp.pName) as names
FROM lp
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT pID
  FROM lp
  GROUP BY pID
  HAVING count(pID) > 1
) dup ON lp.pID = dup.pID
group by lp.pID
```

Which works, but now I am trying to extend it such that it only pulls the 938 that have mismatched pName values.  Nothing that I try seems to work.  How can I get that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT lp.pID, group_concat(lp.lpID) as lpIDs, group_concat(lp.pName) as names
FROM lp
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT pID, COUNT(distinct pName) AS Names
  FROM lp
  GROUP BY pID
  HAVING count(pID) > 1 AND Names > 1
) dup ON lp.pID = dup.pID
group by lp.pID
```